# Anyone know how nosetest's -m, -i and -e work?

Tags: python, regex, unit-testing, nosetests

I am trying to get nosetests to identify my tests but it is not running any of my tests properly.

I have the following file structure

```
Project
    +----Foo/
          +----__init__.py
          +----bar.py
    +----test/
          +----__init__.py
          +----unit/
                +----__init__.py
                +----bar_test.py
          +----functional/
                +----__init__.py
                +----foo_test.py
```

Within bar_test.py

```
class BarTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def bar_1_test():
         ...
```

Within foo_test.py

```
class FooFTest.py
     def foo_1_test():
         ...
```

Using -m, -i, -e options of nosetests

- What is the regex I need to run only unit tests (under unit/, tests in class BarTest)
- What is the regex I need run only functional tests (under functional/, tests in class FooFTest)

I've tried various combinations and can't seem to get nosetests to do what I want consistently

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to run only the tests under `Project/test/unit` is to use `--where`. For example:

```
nosetests --where=Project/test/unit
```

Then use `--match` (`-m`) or `--exclude` (`-e`) to refine the list, if needed.

If you still want to use the regex selectors, you can probably do it like this (not tested):

```
nosetests --match='^Foo[\b_\./-])[Tt]est'
```

Executing this script from the `Project` directory would run all tests that start with "Foo" and end in "[Tt]est".

As a general rule, you probably want to use either `--match` or `--exclude`, but not both. These parameters both specify the pattern of the *function names* to match. You can refine either one by using `--ignore-files` which, naturally, allows you to ignore whole files.

Comment: so --match and --exclude only match the test methods and not the test class name?

Comment: Oops. Good catch. You're right. From the docs for --match: "Files, directories, function names, and class names that match this regular expression are considered tests." So you could use --match to collect all tests, then use --exclude to ignore the ones that contain "bar", for example.

Answer (score 3):

Given your directory structure, you can easily run segments of the tests using the --exclude option.

**Run all tests:**

```
nosetests Project
```

**Run unit tests:**

```
nosetests Project -e functional
```

**Run functional tests:**

```
nosetests Project -e unit
```

If you have more complex test execution needs, I'd recommend marking the tests and using [the attrib package](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html).